# How to apply window function like rollingaverage to all the columns in google dataprep?

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep, data-preprocessing

I have dataset with timestamp and multiple sensor variables. `dataset dimension = (50000,100).`
I can apply function for single column on dataprep for rolling average: `ROLLINGAVERAGE("Column_name", 21, 0).`
Is there any way to apply the same function to all the columns in gcp dataprep.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://docs.trifacta.com/display/DP/ROLLINGAVERAGE+Function#:%7E:text=multiple%20columns%20and%20wildcards%20are%20not%20supported.) of TriFacta:

> Multiple columns and wildcards are not supported.